# Conditional forwarding of messages using @SendTo on @KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I am contemplating to use the `@SendTo` annotation with the `@KafkaListener` annotation. I will be receiving a message, will be doing minimal computation which will be no more than one method call. Though, that method has the potential of throwing an exception. In such a scenario, I will be throwing and then catching the exception(Want to catch it). In such a scenario, is it possible to not forward the object/string onto the topic, because in my system an exception occurring should be reason enough, that the object/string is malformed and not fit for further use?

EDIT-

So I was thinking something similar to we have in @cacheable- unless?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `@Cacheable.unless()` is a bit misleading here:

```
/**
 * Spring Expression Language (SpEL) expression used to veto method caching.
 * <p>Unlike {@link #condition}, this expression is evaluated after the method
 * has been called and can therefore refer to the {@code result}.
```

You see it is performed against the method result. In your case you are talking about an exception, so you need to consider to use `@KafkaListener.errorHandler()` which works like this:

```
catch (ListenerExecutionFailedException e) {
        if (this.errorHandler != null) {
            try {
                Object result = this.errorHandler.handleError(message, e, consumer);
                if (result != null) {
                    handleResult(result, record, message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException(createMessagingErrorMessage(
                        "Listener error handler threw an exception for the incoming message",
                        message.getPayload()), ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

So, in your case do not propagate a wrong message to the `@SendTo` you should just return nothing from the `KafkaListenerErrorHandler.handleError()`.

Comment: Right; just return `null` from the listener or add an error handler that returns `null`. Either one will suppress sending anything out.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about returning null from the method annotated with @kafkalistener. If that works, it’s good enough for me.(perhaps not the most elegant solution)

Comment: Any particular advantage other than convenience for using sendto compared to creating a producer and wrapping it in a Kafka template and then sending it. I know for  @sendto , we would do the same(as in create a producer , put it in Kafka template) and then configure concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory’s reply template property with the Kafka template. But anything other than convenience?

Comment: You have just explained how that `@SendTo` mechanism works underneath

Comment: I meant to ask the real reason behind adding the @SendTo annotation? Any advantage using it unless convenience?